# Using a Type I Nested Query for a Difference Problem

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on my homework and am having trouble figuring out the correct syntax for the "NOT IN" functionality.

The database is a small insurance database (carriers, members, employers, plans) made up for this assignment.  I am supposed to figure out "Which Plans do not have any Member subscriptions?  List the PlanID, the plnDescription and plnCost.  (Hint: use the nested Select statement with a NOT IN clause.)"

This is what I have written as of right now:

```
SELECT planid, plndescription, plncost
FROM plans
WHERE planid NOT IN
(SELECT memberno FROM members);
```

And when I run that query, I get a 0 rows selected response.

When I take out the WHERE statement, I get the following response:

```
PLANID                 PLNDESCRIPTION                      PLNCOST
---------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------------
1                      Single Basic Medical                72.5
2                      2-Party Basic Medical               140
3                      Family Basic Medical                225
4                      Single SuperMed                     110
5                      2-Party SuperMed                    200
6                      Family SuperMed                     350
7                      Single Dental Only                  35
8                      Family Dental Only                  70
9                      Life Only                           16.5
10                     Single SuperMed with Dental         125
11                     2-Party SuperMed with Dental        240
12                     Family SuperMed with Dental         425

12 rows selected
```

I'm sure my error is in the WHERE statement because I'm sure I'm using the wrong field names in the WHERE statement as well as the second SELECT statement. Any help is very much appreciated.

Members table structure:

```
Name                           Null     Type
------------------------------ -------- -------------
MEMBERNO                       NOT NULL NUMBER
MBRFIRSTNAME                            CHAR(35)
MBRLASTNAME                             CHAR(35)
MBRSTREET                               CHAR(50)
MBRCITY                                 CHAR(30)
MBRSTATE                                CHAR(2)
MBRZIP                                  CHAR(10)
MBRPHONENO                              CHAR(10)
PLANID                                  NUMBER
MBREMAIL                                CHAR(255)
MBRDATEEFFECTIVE                        DATE
EMPLOYERID                              NUMBER

12 rows selected
```

Plans Table Structure:

```
Name                Null     Type
------------------- -------- -------------
PLANID              NOT NULL NUMBER
PLNDESCRIPTION               CHAR(35)
PLNCOST                      NUMBER(8,2)
CARRIERID                    CHAR(4)

4 rows selected
```

Comment: Could you provide Members and Plan table structure?

Comment: In particular, does the MEMBERS table have a PLANID column (hint, hint)

Comment: @andr: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @Jeff, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 4):

In your query, you have a where clause that is looking PlanIDs that are not present in the list of MemberNos that you get from your sub query. But, your subquery is running a select on MemberNos instead of PlanIds.

So what you are doing is looking for PlanIds in a list of MemberNos. And so, obviously SQL isn't able to find any records. Instead you will have to look for PlanIDs in a list of PlanIds.

Edit according to your member table. You can use this-

```
SELECT planid, plndescription, plncost FROM plans WHERE planid not IN (SELECT PlanID FROM Members)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing PLANS.PLANID with MEMBERS.MEMBERNO.  I suspect that this isn't what you meant to do.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that planId is in members

```
SELECT planid, plndescription, plncost
FROM plans
WHERE planid not IN
(SELECT planid FROM members);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Members table is linked to Plans table through the **PLANID** foreign key this query should work:

```
SELECT p.planid, p.plndescription, p.plncost
FROM plans p
WHERE p.planid NOT IN
(SELECT m.planid FROM members m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the NOT EXISTS clause instead of NOT IN. NOT IN returns 0 record if a NULL is returned by subquery but NOT Exists gives the correct result. For more details please check this article:

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/21/32/

Comment: The PlanID is specified as not null in the Plans table, so we could assume that a proper foreign key is setup on the members table to prevent nulls, but in general your point is valid. +1.

Comment: SELECT planid, plndescription, plncost
FROM plans p WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM members m WHERE m.planid=p.planid);